# If I visit and leave a Schengen country on the same day, does it count as +1 day?

Tags: visas, schengen, long-stay-visas

I'm from Croatia, and I can enter any Schengen country with my ID (I don't need a visa for it). The thing is that I used all my 90 days. (I didn't go over 90 days).

There is a high possibility that I would need to enter a Schengen country again for a job interview.

Can I enter the Schengen country, and leave on the same day? Will it count as +1 day towards my time spent in the Schengen area?

If so, is there a way I can extend it? Present work papers, etc.

Comment: Do you have a Croatian passport?

Comment: If you're a Croatian citizen, then you're also an EU citizen. As such, you have the right to travel to and be present in any EU country as much as you wish. The 90/180 limit only applies to third-country (i. e. non-EU, non-EEA, non-Swiss) nationals.

Comment: @RichardBeasley I don't have at the moment, but I can make one.And ach Croatia is EU country but it's not in the Schengen. So the rule applies to us as well

Comment: @ach This is not entirely correct eg the 90/180 limit also applies to U.K. citizens despite their current status as EU citizens.

Comment: `Can I enter the Schengen country, and leave on the same day? Will it count as +1 day towards my already 90 days in Schengen?` Yes and Yes per the [Schengen Calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en)

Comment: @Traveller I'm pretty sure that's not true (as in, I have immediate family members who have used their UK nationality to go and stay in France for much longer than that).  What makes you think so?

Comment: @Madhatter Source https://www.gov.uk/government/news/visa-free-access-to-eu-schengen-area

Comment: @Traveller That covers a variety of types of British passports that are not British citizenship. British citizens have free movement, others do not.

Comment: Citizens of non-Schengen EU countries can stay in Schengen countries as long as they want unless there is a limitation for new EU countries. UK citizens can live in Spain for instance. I am not sure about Croatia.

Comment: @Dino Schengen zone is about lack of border control, but that's an absolutely separate question from one's freedoms and rights. EU citizens may be present in the EU where they want and as much as they want - that's a freedom granted by the EU treaty.

Comment: @Willeke: There are some restrictions on freedom of movements, though they are considerably more liberal than what holds for visa-free third-country nationals. (An EU citizen who is neither studying, working, looking for work, or economically self-sufficient, etc., cannot decide to relocate to another EU country indefinitely). That doesn't apply to the OP, who is explicitly seeking work, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm seeking work (provided you're not taking the piss, eg by looking for work as a doctor without having any medical training) doesn't make you ineligible for protection under the directive, see [Article 14 sec 4 para b](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004L0038&from=EN).

Comment: @HenningMakholm oh, OK, so we're passionately agreeing that the OP has the right to do what (s)he proposes to do, yes?

Comment: @MadHatter: Yes. (I was saying the _restrictions_ don't apply to the OP, not that freedom of movement doesn't apply).

Comment: @HenningMakholm excellent, and I apologise for not realising that sooner!

Comment: Little update here: I just called the Croatian Ministry of Foreign Affairs to confirm that. I've been told that unfortunately Schengen limit does apply to me since Croatia is not in Schengen, despite being part of the EEA

Answer (score 5):

As a Croatian national, you are an EU citizen, and your rights with regard to free movement are currently governed by [the citizens' rights directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizens%E2%80%99_Rights_Directive).  This explicitly provides that EU (strictly, EEA) citizens can work in countries other than their own, which explicitly includes "*looking for work for a reasonable amount of time*".  You should be fine to travel to any other EEA country for a job interview on your Croatian passport; Schengen limits do not apply to you, as they don't to a full citizen of any EEA member nation.

Comment: I just called the Croatian Ministry of Foreign Affairs to confirm that. I've been told that unfortunately Schengen limit does apply to me since Croatia is not in Schengen, despite being part of the EEA.

Comment: Yes I am 100% Croatian citizen. I was born there, and I live there

Comment: God forbid I claim to know more about this than your government (or at least its call centre) but you might want to read the text of the directive, [in Croatian](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/HR/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004L0038&from=EN), for yourself, and see what you think.  Enough rubbish is talked in my country, including by my government and [its high officers of state](https://bit.ly/2uja7VT), about the rights and obligations of EU membership, that I don't necessarily trust them to get it right.

Comment: Indeed it says that 3 months is the maximum I can stay without any formal papers. Thank you! I guess I will try to sort out my work papers and then hope I'll manage to get around the +1 day somehow.

Comment: @Dino You don't need any papers. This 3 month limit only applies to residence. There are no conditions on simply traveling.

Comment: @Dino The Ministry of Foreign Affairs is talking nonsense.

Comment: "You should be fine to travel... on your Croatian passport". But in answer to my comment above "Do you have a Croatian passport?" the OP replied: "I don't have at the moment, but I can make one". Perhaps the lack of a passport is the problem.

Comment: @Dino indeed, it does not.